# How to reset/reinitalize variables?

Tags: python, variables

I've ran into an problem with variables. First see this code then I will explain my problem:

```py
if pygame.Rect.colliderect(hammer_rect, mole_rect):
    random_locations = [(100, 440), (350, 440), (600, 440), (100, 260), (350, 260), (600, 260), (100, 80),
                        (350, 80), (600, 80)]

    randomsucks = random.choice(random_locations)
    test_sucks = randomsucks
    mole_spawn_new(randomsucks[0], randomsucks[1])
    randomsucks = 0
    score += 1
    print('Score was increased by one ')
```

I want that when it runs again, the random numbers can't be same again. This is the related to the spawn of the enemy in my game and it is spawning at the same location after dying. I don't wanted it to go that way, so I tried to do this:

```py
if pygame.Rect.colliderect(hammer_rect, mole_rect):
    random_locations = [(100, 440), (350, 440), (600, 440), (100, 260), (350, 260), (600, 260), (100, 80),
                        (350, 80), (600, 80)]

    randomsucks = random.choice(random_locations)
    while randomsucks == test_sucks:
        if test_sucks == randomsucks:
            randomsucks = random.choice(random_locations)
    test_sucks = randomsucks
    mole_spawn_new(randomsucks[0], randomsucks[1])
    randomsucks = 0
    score += 1
    print('Score was increased by one ')
```

Nut that didn't work because I was using the variable before defining it.

Comment: Just define: `test_sucks = None` at the top of your program.

Comment: wait does that actually work

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: it dosent gives me the error but the objective of it is still left out the enemy can still spawn at the same place i just tried

Comment: wait i didnt tried in edited version it might actually work

Comment: no bro it dosent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well I think I get the problem here.

One approach would be to remove the item from the list each time you generate a random item.

Another way you can do this is by using 2 random items: x and y, this way the probability that you will get the same point is not very likely.

But If you can't use these solutions then you can change the random seed:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_seed.asp

Comment: nice idea but there is a bit of a problem in the first approach i want to do it infinitely but some changes can be made i think i can do that i can delete it from this list and make another list of deleted items after the code is ran the second time i can .append it from the deleted list nice idea thx and for the second one i am trying to do that the enemy can only spawn in 9 places so that is a bit off and the third link pls tell me how to use it

Comment: maybe mine can help?

Comment: when i told you about the first approach I meant that you remove each item until the list is empty and then you reinitialize the list from 0 to the initial state, so you can keep going forever.
list [a,b,c] -> list[a,c] -> list[a] -> list[a,b,c] .....

Comment: yeah that is a lot easier deleting items thx (I am the lazy guy who only does the easy stuff)

Answer (score 2):

To stop the same number from being used again:

```
from random import choice
blacklisted_numbers = [] #this might need to be global if you want to use this function multiple times
random_locations = [(100, 440), (350, 440), (600, 440), (100, 260), (350,260), (600, 260), (100, 80),(350, 80), (600, 80)]
number = choice(random_locations)
while number in blacklisted_numbers:
   number = choice(random_locations)
#now its out of the loop so its not blacklisted
#Code all of your stuff
blacklisted_numbers.append(number)
```

For summary what my thinking is that if you create an empty array you can append all used random_locations there and assign a random choice to the number and when it hits the while loop, if the first assigned value is not in there the loop will not run and it will run your code then after all of that you blacklist the tuple. If this was not what you are asking please clarify more

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is to move the locations to the top of the program:

```py
random_locations = [(100, 440), (350, 440), (600, 440), (100, 260), (350, 260), (600, 260), (100, 80), (350, 80), (600, 80)]
test_sucks = None

if pygame.Rect.colliderect(hammer_rect, mole_rect):
    randomsucks = random.choice(random_locations)
    while randomsucks == test_sucks:
        randomsucks = random.choice(random_locations)
    test_sucks = randomsucks
    ...
    # use randomsucks
```

Comment: thx will just try to do it sound the simpliest to me

Comment: The idea here is that you will always get a different location and never 'run out'. There may be rare occasions where it will seem to alternate between two locations, but that is a random chance.

Comment: i tried all and nothin worked thanks god