# Spawning of the enemy spawns at the same place every time

Tags: python, pygame, 2d, spawn

You can see my problem on this question:
[How to reset/reinitalize variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72078717/how-to-reset-reinitalize-variables).

After seeing the answers I changed my function to this:

```
def spawn():
    global blacklisted_numbers
    blacklisted_numbers = []  # this might need to be global if you want to use
                              # this function multiple times
    random_locations = [(100, 440), (350, 440), (600, 440), (100, 260), (350, 260),
                        (600, 260), (100, 80), (350, 80), (600, 80)]
    number = choice(random_locations)
    while number in blacklisted_numbers:
        number = choice(random_locations)
    blacklisted_numbers.append(number)
    print(number)
    print(len(blacklisted_numbers))
    print(len(random_locations))
    pos1 = number[0]
    pos2 = number[1]
    print(pos1, pos2)
    global final_pos
    final_pos = (pos1 + 65)
    global final_pos_2
    final_pos_2 = (pos2 - 7)
    global mole
    mole = pygame.image.load('small_mole.png')
    global mole_rect
    mole_rect = mole.get_rect(center=(final_pos, final_pos_2))
    screen.blit(mole, mole_rect)
```

Still nothing worked out.

This is all the code:

```
import pygame
from sys import exit
import random
from random import choice

pygame.init()

molepos1 = 0
molepos2 = 0
looptime = 8


def spawn():
    global blacklisted_numbers
    blacklisted_numbers = []  # this might need to be global if you want to use
                              # this function multiple times
    random_locations = [(100, 440), (350, 440), (600, 440), (100, 260), (350, 260),
                        (600, 260), (100, 80), (350, 80), (600, 80)]
    number = choice(random_locations)
    while number in blacklisted_numbers:
        number = choice(random_locations)
    blacklisted_numbers.append(number)
    print(number)
    print(len(blacklisted_numbers))
    print(len(random_locations))
    pos1 = number[0]
    pos2 = number[1]
    print(pos1, pos2)
    global final_pos
    final_pos = (pos1 + 65)
    global final_pos_2
    final_pos_2 = (pos2 - 7)
    global mole
    mole = pygame.image.load('small_mole.png')
    global mole_rect
    mole_rect = mole.get_rect(center=(final_pos, final_pos_2))
    screen.blit(mole, mole_rect)


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption(' Whack a mole')
icon = pygame.image.load('whack-a-mole-icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# the screen and the game
screen.fill((0, 255, 0))
background = pygame.image.load('green-grass-background-2036900.jpg').convert_alpha()
score = 0

spawn()

# everything releated to the mole with the mole of course
mole = pygame.image.load('small_mole.png')
mole_home = pygame.image.load('land.png')
mole_home = pygame.transform.scale(mole_home, (130, 80))
mole_rect = mole.get_rect(center=(final_pos, final_pos_2))
# hammer
hammer = pygame.image.load('hammer.png')
hammer2 = pygame.image.load('hammer2.png')
hammer3 = pygame.image.load('hammer3.png')
whyamiahammer = hammer2

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
            if event.button == 1:
                whyamiahammer = hammer3
                collision = pygame.Rect.colliderect(hammer_rect, mole_rect)
                if collision == True:
                    spawn()
                    screen.blit(mole, mole_rect)
                    score += 1
                    print('Score was increased by one ')
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            whyamiahammer = hammer2
    hammerx, hammery = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    hammer_rect = hammer3.get_rect(center=(hammerx, hammery))

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(mole,mole_rect)
    screen.blit(mole_home, (100, 440))
    screen.blit(mole_home, (350, 440))
    screen.blit(mole_home, (600, 440))
    screen.blit(mole_home, (100, 260))
    screen.blit(mole_home, (350, 260))
    screen.blit(mole_home, (600, 260))
    screen.blit(mole_home, (100, 80))
    screen.blit(mole_home, (350, 80))
    screen.blit(mole_home, (600, 80))
    screen.blit(whyamiahammer, ((hammerx) - 61, (hammery - 73)))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to init `blacklisted_numbers` before the `spawn` function. Reset the list when all random locations are in the list:

```py
blacklisted_numbers = [] 
def spawn():
    global blacklisted_numbers
    random_locations = [(100, 440), (350, 440), (600, 440), (100, 260), (350, 260), (600, 260), (100, 80), (350, 80),
                        (600, 80)]
    if len(blacklisted_numbers) == len(random_locations):
        blacklisted_numbers = [] 

    # [...]
```

Alternatively you can remove the items from `random_locations`:

```py
random_locations = [] 
def spawn():
    global random_locations
    if not random_locations:
        random_locations = [(100, 440), (350, 440), (600, 440), (100, 260), (350, 260), (600, 260), (100, 80), (350, 80),
                            (600, 80)]
    number = choice(random_locations)
    random_locations.remove(number)

    # [...]
```